# Recursive function causing my script to exit

Tags: autohotkey

When I call this function it runs for a few minutes and then the script exits. I have found if I set the sleep period higher it takes longer for it to exit. Are there any ways I can write this so that it never exits? I think it has to do with the memory being used. The delay between loops has to be 500ms or lower.

```
Waitbeforefight()
{
    Random, Wbf, 500, 500
    sleep %Wbf%
    ImageSearch, FoundX2, FoundY2, 855, 915, 1024, 1071, *30 E:\Desktop\Capture23.png
    if ErrorLevel = 2
    {
        MsgBox Could not conduct the search.
        ExitApp
    }
    else if ErrorLevel = 1
    {
        return
    }
    else
    {
        sleep %Wbf%
        Waitbeforefight()
    }
}
```

Even when I make a simple script like this it exits.

```
func1()
{
    sleep 50    
    func1()
}

F1::
{
    func1()
}
```

Comment: It exits because the stack overflows: both of functions call *themselves*, and never return. Change the recursive call into a continuous loop to solve it.

Comment: Haha funny. Can I put a loop and then more if..then statements inside of a loop inside of an if..then statement? Could you give an example? With the first one it does return once it finds the image, that's what I want it to do. I want it to continue forever until it finds the image. Thanks!

Comment: Sorry, I can't give you an example because I have no idea what sort of programming language this is. Does it come with a manual?

Comment: It's Autohotkey. Yes it does, there is documentation online. It's fine though, I can ask somewhere else.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As Jongware commented,

> It exits because the stack overflows: both of functions call *themselves*, and never return. Change the recursive call into a continuous loop to solve it.

After attempting an image search, there are three paths your function can take:

- If the search couldn't be conducted, the script exits.
- If the image wasn't found, the function returns.
- Otherwise, the image was found and the function repeats.

Since the first two cases are exiting the function, it is very simple to change your function to use a loop: just remove the recursive call and wrap the content of the function in a `Loop {}`.

```
Waitbeforefight()
{
    Loop
    {
        Random, Wbf, 500, 500
        sleep %Wbf%
        ImageSearch, FoundX2, FoundY2, 855, 915, 1024, 1071, *30 E:\Desktop\Capture23.png
        if ErrorLevel = 2
        {
            MsgBox Could not conduct the search.
            ExitApp
        }
        else if ErrorLevel = 1
        {
            return
        }
        else
        {
            sleep %Wbf%
            ; Instead of calling self, just allow the loop to continue.
        }
    }
}
```